# In React Native, how can a user get to the previous page the user last visitted even after quitting the app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, screen

After doing some reasearch on it, it seems like making use of  `navigation state` in React navigation is good to get started.
So, I was reading the officual document and tring to see what it's like on the demo app "Snack". [https://reactnavigation.org/docs/state-persistence/#:~:text=Try%20this%20example%20on%20Snack](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/state-persistence/#:%7E:text=Try%20this%20example%20on%20Snack)

However, it simply doesn't work. Whenever refreshing the app, it just makes me start the first screen. I also copied the codes and tried that on VS code, but the result was the same. Maybe is it just me?? The app always starts with the first page, not the screen you last visited.

Now, I'm stack. Here is the official doc.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/state-persistence/

Is there anyone who makes use of this thing for that? or any alternative out there?
I need some help. If you have time and could take a look at the link, it'd be nice!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this, I finally fixed it.
In my environment, I just use a normal app created by

`npx create-expo-app AwesomeProject` with ios simulator.

Here are the codes from the official website.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Platform, View, Button, Linking, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const SettingsStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function A() {
  return <View />;
}

function B({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Go to C" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('C')} />
    </View>
  );
}

function C({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Go to D" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('D')} />
    </View>
  );
}

function D() {
  return <View />;
}

function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen name="A" component={A} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function SettingsStackScreen() {
  return (
    <SettingsStack.Navigator>
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="B" component={B} />
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="C" component={C} />
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="D" component={D} />
    </SettingsStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const PERSISTENCE_KEY = 'NAVIGATION_STATE_V1';

export default function App() {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = React.useState(false);
  const [initialState, setInitialState] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const restoreState = async () => {
      try {
        const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL();

        if (Platform.OS !== 'web' && initialUrl == null) {
          const savedState = await AsyncStorage.getItem(PERSISTENCE_KEY);
          const state = savedState ? JSON.parse(savedState) : undefined;

          if (state !== undefined) {
            setInitialState(state);
          }
        }
      } finally {
        setIsReady(true);
      }
    };

    if (!isReady) {
      restoreState();
    }
  }, [isReady]);

  if (!isReady) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      initialState={initialState}
      onStateChange={(state) =>
        AsyncStorage.setItem(PERSISTENCE_KEY, JSON.stringify(state))
      }
    >
      <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeStackScreen}
          options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Home!' }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Settings"
          component={SettingsStackScreen}
          options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Settings!' }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And here are the codes that works out of the box.
I just removed two parts:

"const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL();"
"iinitialUrl == null"

That's it!
Since most people especially who just started learning react native use `npx create-expo-app AwesomeProject` to set it up, you could have the same issue and could be stack like me.
And most of the time, when you want to learn a new thing, you want to first learn the structure first and want to know how it works, but if some kinf of official document doesn't work out of the box, then that would just makes it difficult to learn new things.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Platform, View, Button, Linking, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const SettingsStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function A() {
  return <View />;
}

function B({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Go to C" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('C')} />
    </View>
  );
}

function C({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Go to D" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('D')} />
    </View>
  );
}

function D() {
  return <View />;
}

function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen name="A" component={A} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function SettingsStackScreen() {
  return (
    <SettingsStack.Navigator>
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="B" component={B} />
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="C" component={C} />
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="D" component={D} />
    </SettingsStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const PERSISTENCE_KEY = 'NAVIGATION_STATE_V1';

export default function App() {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = React.useState(false);
  const [initialState, setInitialState] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const restoreState = async () => {
      try {
        const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL();

        if (Platform.OS !== 'web' && initialUrl == null) {
          const savedState = await AsyncStorage.getItem(PERSISTENCE_KEY);
          const state = savedState ? JSON.parse(savedState) : undefined;

          if (state !== undefined) {
            setInitialState(state);
          }
        }
      } finally {
        setIsReady(true);
      }
    };

    if (!isReady) {
      restoreState();
    }
  }, [isReady]);

  if (!isReady) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      initialState={initialState}
      onStateChange={(state) =>
        AsyncStorage.setItem(PERSISTENCE_KEY, JSON.stringify(state))
      }
    >
      <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeStackScreen}
          options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Home!' }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Settings"
          component={SettingsStackScreen}
          options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Settings!' }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Hope this will help someone trying to learn React Native!